# Most efficient way to store collection of partially shared strings in memory

Tags: c#, arrays, string, memory, recursion

I have a recursive C# app that iterates through a tree and needs to maintain a history of all nodes in the chain whenever the last node equals X.

For example, I'm searching for the word MATCH below

```
Root
 |
 |-Node1
 |   |-Sub1
 |   |-MATCH
 |
 |-Node2
 |   |-Node22
 |   |-Node33
 |   |   |-MATCH
 |   |-Node3
 |
 |-Node3
 |   |-Node88
     |-MATCH
```

Notice how Node3 is a sibling to Node2.  My goal is to determine the parent child relationship between root and every path that encounters a MATCH.  That means that the following output is generated:

```
   Root -> Node1 -> MATCH
   Root -> Node2 -> Node33 -> MATCH
   Root -> Node2 -> Node3  -> MATCH
   Root -> Node3 -> MATCH
```

What is the right way to approach coding this?

I see immediately that any attempt of tracking deep or long paths will result in most memory being consumed for tracking paths that have no value.  The only paths that have value are those listed above wherein a match is found

My goal is to implement this on Azure Table or Blob storage... in batches of 100 rows per IO query, with up to 20,000 rows ever queried per level in the heiarchy.

I'm sure this has been done before but don't know what it would be called..

**Question**

How should I refer to the strings in memory so that they consume the least amount of RAM?

**Example Answer:**

Use a struct with the ref parameter... or...

```
Struct MyMemoryData
{
    public string PreviousNode {get;set;}
    public string NodeName {get;set;}
}

void MyRecursion(MyMemoryData searchStack, List<string> nodesToQuery)
{
    foreach(var str in nodesToQuery)
    {
        var newToDoList = GetChildNodes(str);

        searchStack.PreviousNode = searchStack.CurentNode;
        searchStack.CurrentNode = str;
        MyRecursion(searchStack, newToDoList);
    }
}
```

or save a ref to the struct

```
 Struct MyMemoryData
    {
        public MyMemoryData PreviousNode {get;set;}  // this line was changed: Type is MyMemoryData
        public string NodeName {get;set;}
    }

    void MyRecursion(MyMemoryData searchStack, List<string> nodesToQuery)
    {
        foreach(var str in nodesToQuery)
        {
            var newToDoList = GetChildNodes(str);

            searchStack.PreviousNode = searchStack;  // this line was changed: Saving the object instead of the value
            searchStack.CurrentNode = str;
            MyRecursion(searchStack, newToDoList);
        }
    }
```

Or just keep it all in a List like this:

```
void MyRecursion(List<string> searchStack, List<string> nodesToQuery)
{
    foreach(var str in nodesToQuery)
    {
        var newToDoList = GetChildNodes(str);

        searchStack.Add(str);
        MyRecursion(searchStack, newToDoList);
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you asking for? You need a recursive method which walks down the tree, remembers it's location in the tree and returns all hits. Are you asking for C# data structures? Or the data structure in the database? The most efficient way to do that? ...?

Comment: So if Node3 is "under" Node2, such that you get Root -> Node2 -> Node3, why don't you get Root -> Node1 -> Node2 -> Node33, or Root -> Node1 -> Node2 -> Node3? It's not clear what you mean by "under" in this context since Node3 isn't a child of Node2, it's a sibling.

Comment: @MattBurland  I am not trying to count siblings, just the parent child relationship.  I double checked my example and I think it's right.

Comment: @Achim I posted psuedo code to walk the tree, however I don't know the best way to save "searchStack" in memory.  Should it be a class, struct, List<string>, Array?  Should "previous node" be a ref to the class that holds search stack?  I want to memory optimize the function MyRecursion

Comment: Is there anything against the DFS and keeping the (stack of the nodes on the) current path from top? Or you can build a parallel tree whenever you see a match, in a lazy way.

Comment: It's not possible to optimize pseudocode. ;-) There are too many details which you cannot post here but which are relevant for the solution. I would give my node class a method, which searchs in its children. That one walks down the tree. While walking up (returning) the results, I would modifiy the results to show the location in the tree by adding prefixes to the result.

Comment: @makerofthings7 - I still don't understand why `Root -> Node2 -> Node3  -> MATCH` is not `Root -> Node1 -> Node2 -> Node3  -> MATCH`.  Are you saying that nodes can be in multiple places in the tree, so the `Node3` under `Node2` is the same `Node3` that's under `Root`?

Comment: @Bobson, Yes, nodes can be in multiple places similar to a Linux hard link

Answer (score 0):

How many levels do you intend to have?  The size of the stack should be affected by the depth of the tree, not the number of items at each level.

```
void MyRecursion(Stack<string> searchStack, List<string> nodesToQuery)
{
    foreach(var str in nodesToQuery)
    {
        var newToDoList = GetChildNodes(str);

        searchStack.Push(str);
        MyRecursion(searchStack, newToDoList);
        searchStack.Pop(); // make sure to get pop off the current once you are no longer on this level
    }
}
```

EDIT : Honestly I think you might want to consider an iterative approach.  A huge portion of your memory is going to be `newToDoList` being stored at every level of recursion.  If you can run through the tree sequentially (think `XmlReader` which is forward only) and maintain a stack that way, you might be better off.

Comment: I may have up to 512 levels, but 256 in practice.  Each level can have 20,000 siblings.  I'm not sure how to do the math to gauge the RAM required.

Comment: Do you need to maintain the entire path to the matched node, or just the parent of the node?

Comment: I prefer to get the entire path. If there is a memory constraint with this, then I can limit the feature of "entire path" to X levels deep, but I'll have to acknowledge the existence of links that are X+1 (or more)

Comment: @makerofthings7 See my edit, I think you might be trying to save space in the wrong area.

Comment: With a depth first search based approach, it only keeps one path in memory at a time. So the memory required would be equal to the maximum length of each node token * the maximum depth. Unless... you need to keep a list of all the matches until the end and store them. But, you shouldn't need to store the path for anything that has no match

Comment: Do you have a link to the parent node in the node class? If so, it could affect the best solution

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for a map reduction algorithm.

Others have mentioned [MapReduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) as a potential option; and some people have worked on using that in Azure.

There are a number of articles / algorithms out there, such as [this link](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/rjw/csu390-f06/HowTo/How-to-Create-Mapping-Reductions.pdf) that will help you craft your own.